# I am trying to print "ok" but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, validation, while-loop

I am trying to print `"ok"` but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```py
def passvalidation(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        print('password must be at least 8 characters')
    elif password.isnumeric():
        print("your password must contain at least one letter")
    elif password.isalpha():
        print("your password must contain at least one number")
    else:
        print("your password is correct")


while True:
    password = input("enter your password: ")
    passvalidation(password)


print("ok")
```

Why isn't `"ok"` being printed?

Comment: When do you expect the `while True` loop to exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers haven't really addresses your largest problem.  `passvalidation` should return a value, either `True` or `False`, based on whether the password was valid or not.

```
def passvalidation(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        print('password must be at least 8 characters')
    elif password.isnumeric():
        print("your password must contain at least one letter")
    elif password.isalpha():
        print("your password must contain at least one number")
    else:
        print("your password is correct")
        return True
    return False

while True:
    password = input("enter your password: ")
    if passvalidation(password):
        break

print("ok")
```

As a general rule, a function should serve one purpose.  If your function is supposed to validate passwords, then have it DO that, but it shouldn't print anything.  It should be up to the caller to decide what to DO with the information.  In this case, you could return an error message:

```
def passvalidation(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        return 'password must be at least 8 characters'
    elif password.isnumeric():
        return "your password must contain at least one letter"
    elif password.isalpha():
        return "your password must contain at least one number"
    else:
        return None

while True:
    password = input("enter your password: ")
    err = passvalidation(password)
    if err:
        print(err)
    else:
        break

print("ok")
```

NOW you can reuse that function in some other program that doesn't have a console at all.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why "ok" isn't getting printed is because it's not part of the code you provided. In your code, you're only printing the validation messages based on the password entered. If you want to print "ok" after the password validation, you need to add a print statement with "ok" inside the else block of your passvalidation() function. Here's an updated version of your code:

```py
def passvalidation(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        print('password must be at least 8 characters')
    elif password.isnumeric():
        print("your password must contain at least one letter")
    elif password.isalpha():
        print("your password must contain at least one number")
    else:
        print("your password is correct")
        print("ok")


while True:
    password = input("enter your password: ")
    passvalidation(password)
```

Now, after validating the password, if it meets the criteria, it will print "ok" as well.

Answer (score 0):

A `while True` is an infinite loop. This means that your program will never print "ok", unless you break out of the loop. The `break` statement in python lets you break out of any loop.

Perhaps you meant the `print("ok")` to be inside the `while True` loop. In that case, you need to indent the `print("ok")` by one block to put it inside the loop.

```
while True:
    password = input("enter your password: ")
    passvalidation(password)

    print("ok")
```

Comment: Thanks
Because I'm just learning, I didn't pay attention to the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since your while loop never gonna stop(it is infinite).
you can put that print statement in while loop instead.

```
while True:
    password = input("enter your password: ")
    passvalidation(password)
 
    print("ok")
```